# Best Practice for properties in ScalaSpark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, properties

I'm starting a project using Hadoop Spark. I'll be developing in Scala.
I'm creating the project from scratch and I was wondering what to do with properties.

I come from a Java Background where I use .properties file and load them at the start. Then I have a class used to access the different value of my properties.

Is this also a good practice in Scala ?

Tried googling, but there isn't anything relating to this.

Comment: It's more a question for chat or slack - please see http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127924/apache-spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we do:

1. scopt.OptionParser to parse command line arguments.
2. key/value arguments `conf` are replicated to System.properties
3. command line arg `config-file` is used to read config file (using spark context to be able to read from S3/HDFS with custom code path to be able to read from jar resources)
4. config file parsed using com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.
5. Default configs from resources and from read file are combined using the `withFallback` mechanism.  The order is important since we want typesafe to use values from (2) to override thoses from the files.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the properties file in scala similar to Java

```
import scala.io.Source.fromUrl
val reader = fromURL(getClass.getResource("conf/fp.properties")).bufferedReader()
```

You can read more about I/O package at [Scala Standard Library I/O](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/io/index.html)

If you are looking to provide spark properties then that have different way of doing it e.g. providing them at time when you submit spark job.

Hoping this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to determine properties for Spark:

- `Spark Propertis` in `SparkConf` [original spec](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-properties):

> Spark properties control most application settings and are configured
>   separately for each application. These properties can be set directly
>   on a SparkConf passed to your SparkContext.

- `Dynamically Loading Spark Properties` [original spec](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties), it avoids hard-coding certain configurations in a SparkConf:

  ./bin/spark-submit --name "My app" --master local[*] --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false
    --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" myApp.jar
- Overriding `spark-defaults.conf` — Default Spark Properties File - [original spec](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/configuration.html#overriding-configuration-directory)

I described properties by priority - `SparkConf` has the highest priority and `spark-conf` has the lowest priority. For more details check [this post](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-properties.html)

If you want to store all properties in the single place, just you [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config). Typesafe Config gets rid of using input streams for reading file, it's widely used the approach in scala app.